# Segregate column to muti-columns based on datetime

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following dataset

```
TRAN_DT;               CONENT; TYPE
01/01/2018 12:00:00;   AAA   ; 1
01/01/2018 12:00:00;   AAA   ; 2
01/01/2018 12:00:00;   AAA   ; 3
01/01/2018 01:00:00;   FFF   ; 1
01/01/2018 01:00:00;   FFF   ; 2
```

I need my result to be like

```
    01/01/2018 12:00:00;01/01/2018 01:00:00
  1 AAA                ;FFF 
  2 AAA                ;FFF
  3 AAA
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select type, 
       max(case when tran_dt = '01/01/2018 12:00:00' then conent end) as c_20180101_12,
       max(case when tran_dt = '01/01/2018 01:00:00' then conent end) as c_20180101_01
from t
group by type
order by type;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY type` and no aggregation around the `CASE` expression?